# Keras evaluation suddenly starts giving unreasonably low accuracy while loss stays the same

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision, google-colaboratory

A couple days ago I trained a Resnet in colab and evaluated it with the following code:

```
model.compile(loss= "sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
              optimizer = optimizer,
              metrics = ["accuracy"]
)

checkpoint_cb = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
                                        filepath= checkpoint_path,
                                        save_weights_only = False,
                                        monitor= 'val_pred_loss',
                                        save_best_only= True
)

tensorboard_cb = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(tensorboard_path)
earlystopping_cb = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience = 6,  monitor="val_pred_loss", min_delta = 0.005)

history = model.fit(
              x = train_set,
              validation_data = val_set,
              validation_steps = 1629//val_b_size,
              epochs = epochs,
              steps_per_epoch = steps_per_epoch,
              callbacks = [checkpoint_cb, tensorboard_cb, earlystopping_cb]
)

best_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(checkpoint_path)
test_set = test_set.batch(17)

print(best_model.evaluate(test_set))
```

The output was `[0.42691513895988464, 0.8850889205932617]`

The model does not have any custom components, it's a simple resnet with new GAP and dense layers for classification, upon rerunning the last 3 lines today I consistently got a nonsensical accuracy `[0.42691513895988464, 0.004352692514657974]`. I initially thought that I changed something in the script by mistake or messed up the file save and load, but the CE loss is the same. How is this possible?

Edit: the issue involves any loaded model, evaluating a trained net directly from RAM works as expected

---

Here's how the model is defined:

```
base_model = keras.applications.ResNet50( include_top = False,
                                            weights = "imagenet",
                                            input_shape = (448, 448, 3),
)

avg = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(base_model.output) # 14 x 14 x 2048 ->2048
o = keras.layers.Dense(196, activation = "softmax")(avg)

model = keras.Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=[o])
```

---

Update: replacing the load_model statement with **model**.load_weights resolves the issue, I'd still like to know the reason.

Comment: I'd like to see the part where you defined the model

Comment: @NicolasGervais Here you are, thanks for the attention.

Comment: how many categories are you working with?

Comment: It's stanford cars, 196 classes, as I said, calling evaluate on model instead of best_model works fine